# Is the VirtualBox DHCP Server accessible to other devices on the host's network?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Host-Only Ethernet Adapter in VirtualBox with DHCP Server Enabled.

Does that DHCP Server only exist between the host machine and it's VirtualBox VMs on a virtual network? Or could other physical machines on the host's network potentially be assigned IP addresses from this DHCP server?

Comment: Shut Down the VM. Open the VM Properties. Set the Network Adapter To Bridged, NOT NAT passthrough. This will enable your VM to have the same IP as your physical machine.  This works opposite from the way your question is phrased but allows devices in your LAN to "see" the VM